# Version conflict of packages with react, react-native, react-dom, react-test-renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom

I am using the latest stable versions of react, react-native, react-test-renderer, react-dom.

Yet react-native has dependencies on react@16.0.0-alpha.12 ;

If I use this version (16.x) of react, then react-dom misbehaves saying it needs react 15.6.1

I am aware of this solution [travis cannot build because Error: Cannot find module 'react-test-renderer/shallow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399407/travis-cannot-build-because-error-cannot-find-module-react-test-renderer-shall/43405910) [the 2nd answer] but it doesn't account for react-native.

Any suggestions of an optimum version match for all given packages?
here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "exampleApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Dom and React follow the same versioning scheme, so it makes sense that react-dom wants to use the same major version of react. Try upgrading *both packages* to  16.x!