# Why are we getting these errors when installing redux packages from terminal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, terminal

We are not sure why we are getting these errors, is there a compatibility issue with the different dependencies and the versions we have installed?

[image]

Comment: Visit this Link. I think this the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399407/travis-cannot-build-because-error-cannot-find-module-react-test-renderer-shall/43401688

Comment: Thank you that helped us resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this? `npm i react-test-renderer`

Answer (score 0):

what package manager are you using?  npm or yarn? 
make sure you are using the latest and a **stable** version of the package manager.

try yarn if you used to use npm.

if that didn't work
remove node_modules/ folder and package-lock.json or the yarn.lock file and try reinstalling node modules again.